# Does sneak attack from both sides of a gestalt character stack?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, homebrew, rogue, sneak-attack, gestalt

If both sides of a gestalt character were classes that grant +5d6 sneak attack by 9th, would I have +10d6 sneak attack at 9th?

(For reference, the classes I am considering for this are both homebrew, but their sneak attack both work like the rogue.)

Comment: Which system & version? There are gestalt rules for multiple versions of D&D and also for Pathfinder.

Comment: yes im sorry it is 3.5e im new here lol my bad

Comment: actually its 2 homebrewed base classes mandrake and some type of ninja i dont remember the exact name

Comment: You might want to include the word 'gestalt' somewhere in your title, as that changes the answer significantly.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

So if you are a rogue//sneak-attack fighter, for example, the answer is no. Each level, you gain the “best value” from each class. For example, a 3rd-level rogue has a +1 bonus to Fort while a 3rd-level fighter has a +3 bonus to Fort—a 3rd-level rogue//fighter has the +3 from fighter, the better number, but not +4, adding the two together. Sneak attack works the same way: at 1st level, both give +1d6, so you take the “better” value (which is +1d6 since they’re tied).

The argument starts when you consider dipping a level of something else on one side. For example, consider a rogue//barbarian/sneak-attack fighter. At 1st level, rogue give +1d6 sneak attack damage, and barbarian gives none. OK, so that’s fine, you get +1d6. At 2nd level, rogue gives no sneak attack damage, but fighter, if you’re now taking your first level of it, give +1d6—so now at 2nd level you have +2d6. At 3rd level, now rogue gives another +1d6 while fighter is “off.”

This “staggering” technique tends to be considered rather poor form, and many DMs won’t allow it. Many will argue that both rogue and sneak-attack fighter give half a sneak attack die each level (rounded up), so you don’t *really* gain +1d6 on one level and +0 on another, but rather gain “+½d6” each level. From this perspective, they wouldn’t stack, because there is no staggering.

On the other hand, you can do this kind of “staggering,” so to speak, *without using gestalt at all* (by taking 1 level in a whole bunch of classes that get +1d6 sneak attack at 1st level; yes, there are enough), which might be a point in favor of being able to do it *with gestalt*.

But ultimately, gestalt is a variant ruleset that is not exactly fully fleshed out, and requires DM adjudication. You need to ask your DM this question, really. For example, *Unearthed Arcana* doesn’t consider the ninja or scout, with their “skirmish” and “sudden strike” damage bonuses that are quite similar to sneak attack. Do *those* stack with sneak attack, e.g. on a rogue//scout? They are very similar, and count as one another for requirements, but by *Unearthed Arcana*’s rules, as written, they would. *Should* they? That I can’t answer—I have played games where it would be fine, I have played other games where it would be overpowered. Ask your DM.

Answer (score 9):

You would only get one sneak attack progression, which ever one is better (or pick one if they are the same)

From the [d20 SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/variant/classes/gestaltCharacters.htm):

> A gestalt character gains the class features of both classes. [...]
>
> A few caveats apply, however.
>
> - Class features that two classes share (such as uncanny dodge) accrue at the rate of the faster class.